# How to create a drop-right menu using bootstrap on a drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've put a drop-down link on the site's NavBar. I want one of the dropdown items to be a different dropright link. In fact, looking to form a dropright menu in another drop-down menu in the site NavBar. How could you handle this job?
I used the following code but the second drop-down menu is not formed. What is the problem?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <span class="dropdown-header" href="#">header</span>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-header">header</span>
                    <div class="dropdown dropright">
                        <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Dropright button
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: share your code..

Comment: I shared the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may give you some ideas on how to implement it.

One of the problems is that the dropright link acts like any other links of the main dropdown menu. This is why it hides once you click on it. You have to manage this separately with jQuery to prevent the main dropdown from closing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropright button').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$(this).next('div').hasClass('show')) {
      $(this).next('div').addClass('show');
    } else {
      $(this).next('div').removeClass('show');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.dropright {
  position: relative;
}

.dropright .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <span class="dropdown-header" href="#">header</span>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <span class="dropdown-header">header</span>
        <div class="dropright">
          <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropright button</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Do you have a suggestion to do it without using JQuery? I am not fluent in a JQuery and usually work with JavaScript

Comment: Not sure that you can do it without JQuery since the dropdown menu from Bootstrap needs it. It would be possible if you make your own dropdown menu in pure css, and showing submenus on hover.